# How to disable a taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am interested in disabling-turning off taxonomy terms.I don't want to delete them so as to enable them later.
How is this possible to do?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Taxonomy Term Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/termstatus) module.

Project page says

> This module adds a status-flag to taxonomy terms. Using this flag it
>   is possible to specify whether terms should be published or not. Users
>   with the appropriate permission may access unpublished terms.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:With the use of Taxonomy manager module,I can move the term to another vocabulary(selecting Double Tree),and when I need the term I can again move to the original voacabulary.
cheers

Comment: I don't know the background why do you want to "disable/turn-off" term(s) but even if you have moved the term to another vocabulary the term is still accessible via `taxonomy/term/tid` path. Maybe [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module would be a better solution.