# Mark a taxonomy term as "deprecated"

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary "categories", and decide that one of the terms should no longer be used (because I introduced another field which covers this information).

I could delete the term, but then some existing content would no longer have a category.

What I would like is to "deprecate" the term, such that

- existing content can continue to reference the term.
- the term is still visible in things like search facets.
- the term can no longer be assigned in a term reference field.
- (optional) editing an existing node which references the old term will fail form validation on save, and force to change the term.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/153115/how-to-disable-a-taxonomy-term , similar question - you can find the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

[Termsatus](https://www.drupal.org/project/termstatus) module can help you.

This add a status "publis" or "unpublish" on terms like nodes, and is handled by permission (that can solve first three points), views, etc.

I think the optional point need a custom code using [hook_node_validate](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7.x) check the status of term an send the custom error message attached to the field.